# How to optimize texture fetching in openGL-ES

Tags: opengl-es

I want to draw a map in shader, which is composed by five textures. One is for the ratios of each texture(CC_Texture0: 512x512), and the other four are different elements(u_tex_r,u_tex_g,u_tex_b,u_tex_a: 256x256).

my shader is:

```
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
#ifdef GL_ES
varying highp vec2 v_uv0;
#else
varying vec2 v_uv0;
#endif

//uniform vec2 repeated_r;
//uniform vec2 repeated_g;
//uniform vec2 repeated_b;
//uniform vec2 repeated_a;

uniform vec4 u_repeat_1;
uniform vec4 u_repeat_2;

uniform sampler2D u_tex_r;
uniform sampler2D u_tex_g;
uniform sampler2D u_tex_b;
uniform sampler2D u_tex_a;

void main()
{
    vec4 mix = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_uv0);

    vec4 r = texture2D(u_tex_r, vec2(v_uv0.x * 20, v_uv0.y * 20));
    vec4 g = texture2D(u_tex_g, vec2(v_uv0.x * 20, v_uv0.y * 20));
    vec4 b = texture2D(u_tex_b, vec2(v_uv0.x * 20, v_uv0.y * 20));
    vec4 a = texture2D(u_tex_a, vec2(v_uv0.x * 20, v_uv0.y * 20));

    gl_FragColor = vec4((r * mix.r + g * mix.g + b * mix.b + a * mix.a).rgb, 1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = vec4((r * mix.r + g * mix.g + b * mix.b).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Device is samsung G5308W, frame rate is only 50 fps, even I delete the scale. When I just print CC_Texture0, frame rate can be 60fps. why? GPU memory or scale? Anybody can help to improve it?

Comment: PS.if "scale" deleted, frame rate will be better. Sorry, the fps is not very stable in this device

Answer (score 2):

Clearly your shader is pretty simple in terms of computation, so I suspect that the thing that is limiting performance is the cost of fetching the teture data. This is not unusual on mobile, memory bandwidth is often the limiting factor for frame-rate and also one of the top contributors to energy use affecting battery life and device heat.

Some suggestions:

- You mentioned that removing the scale doesn't help performance (I presume you mean removing the `* 20` when constructing the UVs). Even if it doesn't have a measurable impact on this device I'd still recommend avoiding the dependent texture read as it will probably slightly improve performance and may improve performance a lot on some older devices. Add a second set of UVs which you can calculate on the vertex shader and pass in as a varying. If you need different scales for each texture then I'd add 4 new varyings. Varyings are very cheap. Don't be tempted to encode multiple UVs into vec4, that might cause dependent texture reads.
- You mention the texture resolution but not the texture format. If you are able to lower the bits-per-pixel of these textures as much as possible you will see a big impact on performance. Compressed textures (e.g. ETC1 which is 4bpp) are best, but even switching from 8888 to 565 or 4444 will also help a lot.
- Could you use a simpler shader in some cases? You haven't mentioned the context, but this has the feel of terrain texture splatting. In terrain you often find that very few chunks of geometry actually use all of the tiled textures. If you can identify geometries which reference fewer textures and use a more specialized fragment shader for those which reference fewer textures, then you would get a good performance boost. The tradeoff is more complex code and potentially more draw calls and state changes which might impact CPU time so it can be a tricky balancing act.
- Finally, the G5308W is a 6 year old device, if you can't hit 60fps on it, then it isn't the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks very much! For the first suggestion, I am not very clear about it. Can you give me a sample? And yes, this is a terrain texture splatting. We will try your suggestions soon.

Comment: Some mobile hardware has a special fast path which allows texture data to be fetched before the fragment shader runs. However, it can only do this if it knows what the UV coordinates are in advance (i.e. the UVs are not dependent on the shader). It is easy to accidentally make a texture read dependent. Your `texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_uv0);` is perfect. Your `texture2D(u_tex_r, vec2(v_uv0.x * 20, v_uv0.y * 20));` is not because the UVs are modifed. Something like `texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_uv0.zw);` would also be problematic. You need `texture2D(u_tex_r, v_uv1);` where `v_uv1` is a new varying.

Comment: Perfect, I know. I tried the same way before by splitting the map into multiple grids and calculate the UV. But I remember the FPS is not improved. But your suggestion is very helpful to me. I will double-check the codes and make further tests. Thanks again!